# Transferring Windows 10 lisence after clean install

Tags: windows-10, license, product-key

I got an SSD and did a clean installation of windows 10 after downloading the official ISO image. The old HDD is still able to boot the old windows 10 installation. Now I need to activate the new installation. How can I transfer the license key from the old installation to the new one? I don't have the original key sticker and didn't write it down.

Comment: If the OS is of the same edition on the same machine, the OS gets automatically activated once it connects to the internet after a clean install.

Comment: Download a Windows 10 ISO, the install Windows 10, skip entering the product code.  That's it.  The installation on the SSD should already be activated, if it isnt, edit your question

Comment: It depends on whether it's a retail / OEM key or if the old windows 10 installation was a free upgrade from win 7/ win 8. With the free upgrade version ('digital license') it is tied to the hardware and will behave as the two previous comments describe. If it was not a free upgrade version, then it does not get tied to your hardware. In that case you will have to boot to your old win 10 installation, recover the key, and use that to activate the new installation. The tool produkey can be used to get your key: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html#DownloadLinks